# Connecting Google Cloud SQL Credentials to Kubernetes Secret

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, gcloud

I am new to Kubernetes and I was playing with it on Google Cloud. I was going through the [google-github-repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/tree/master/cloudsql) and [stcox-gke-wordpress](https://github.com/stcox/gke-wordpress)  I am very confused as to what to provide for the secret `cloudsql-instance-credentials`. After going through some more documentation, I ended up creating a service account and downloaded the JSON Key and tried to provide that as `cloudsql-instance-credentials`.

```
dbCred: {
  type: '',
  project_id: '',
  private_key_id: '',
  private_key: '',
  client_email: '',
  client_id: '',
  auth_uri: '',
  token_uri: '',
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: '',
  client_x509_cert_url: '',
}


apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: cloudsql-instance-credentials
  namespace: wp-{{ .Values.name }}
  labels:
    app: wp-{{ .Values.name }}
type: Opaque
data:
  credentials.json: {{ .Values.dbCred | b64enc }}
```

But I ended up getting this error: `error converting YAML to JSON: did not find expected key`

I am pretty sure I am providing wrong `dbCred`. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your Values.dbCred spans multiple lines, you need to tell yaml that, by using the pipe character |.  Check this out.https://yaml-multiline.info

Answer (score 0):

`cloudsql-instance-credentials` is/are stored as a Kubernetes secret.

You skipped setting up this up. Go back to this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine):